# Altium: error since net connects only to Output Port objects

Tags: altium

I am tasked with creating a schematic (in Altium) which will be instantiated in somebody else's design later. Altium is giving me errors:

[image: A microcontroller GPIO pin connected directly to an output port]

The chip is a microcontroller, and its output goes directly to an output port (so that my colleague can simply make "black-box" connections to my circuit).

However, Altium complains:

```
[Error] Net ADF5355_CLK has only one pin (Pin U1-16)
```

(and similar errors for the other pins as well).

I don't understand this error. Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A named net that does not have a DRC suppression (the X on the unused pins) is considered an error; the tool (indeed, every tool I have ever used) expects a net to connect to at least 2 pins.

When this is used by a higher level (and the pin is connected to something else) the error should disappear.

To fool it for now, you could put a pullup / pulldown resistor on the net to eliminate the error.

See [this article](https://designcontent.live.altium.com/PluginDetail/SinglePinNetReporter) on reporting single pin nets and their definitions.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentions, Altium is essentially saying that the net doesn't go to anything, and is probably not correct.

However, I would avoid doing any tricks to fool Altium to think there is a problem.  Say you put a pullup resistor on that net to fool it for now, and then in the future your colleague instantiates this hierarchy but forgets to connect that net to anything.  Now you won't get an error *but you should* because it's not reflecting your design intent.  Congrats, you just introduced risk that your final design has errors to prevent a compile error at the child cell level.

I think the proper behavior here is to live with the -Error- at the child cell level, knowing that this child cell must be instantiated in a design for it to be correct.  You will need to be compile clean at the top level in the end anyway, so it's overkill (as we see in this case) to be compile clean at the child level.

Don't pull tricks to solve non-problems, in my experience.